# Angular-translate unknown $translateProviderProvider

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, angular-translate

this is my scenario:
I have an Ionic project and I would use angular-translate for the internationalisation.
So I included angular-translate.min.js:

```
<script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
<script src="js/angular-translate.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script src="cordova.js"></script>
```

This is part of the body:

```
<body ng-app="todo" ng-controller="TodoCtrl">
    <ion-side-menus>
        <!-- Center content -->
        <ion-side-menu-content>
            <a href="#chooseBtn" class="button button-icon">
                <i class="icon ion-ios-help-outline "></i>
            </a>
            <h1 class="title" ng-click="test(activeProject.tasks.length)" translate="TITLE">Tap to choose!</h1>
...
```

And this is part of my app.js file:

```
var app = angular.module('todo', ['ionic', 'pascalprecht.translate']).config(['$translateProvider', function ($translateProvider) {
    $translateProvider.translations('en', {
        TITLE: "Tap here to choose!"
    });
    $translateProvider.translations('it', {
        TITLE: "Tocca qui per scegliere!"
    });
}]);


app.factory('Projects', function () {
    return {
        ...
    }
});

app.controller('TodoCtrl', function ($scope, $timeout, $ionicModal, Projects, $ionicSideMenuDelegate, $location, $anchorScroll, $ionicScrollDelegate, $ionicPopup, $translateProvider) {
    $scope.ChangeLanguage = function (lang) {
        $translateProvider.use(lang);
    };

    $timeout(function () {
        $scope.ChangeLanguage("it");
    });
});
```

When I run the project the browser throw me this exception:

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $translateProviderProvider <- $translateProvider <- TodoCtrl
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.3/$injector/unpr?p0=%24translateProviderProvider%20%3C-%20%24translateProvider%20%3C-%20TodoCtrl
    at REGEX_STRING_REGEXP (ionic.bundle.js:8895)
    at ionic.bundle.js:13089
```

*How to solve it?*

Answer (score 1):

I used Angular translate in my project.

1. Download angular-translate from https://github.com/angular-translate/angular-translate
2. first include `<script src="scripts/angular-translate.min.js"></script>` in your index.html.
3. create your language JSON file in your project with all the variables that need to be translated. Note: each language has its specific file. for example:

   **en.json {"email":"Email"},
    ja.json {"email":"電子メール"}**
4. In your app.js inject the `pascalprecht.translate` in your module.
5. In you app.js add: `$translateProvider.useStaticFilesLoader({
       prefix: 'app/languages/', // where all my JSON language files are stored
       suffix: '.json'
   });
6. In you app.js add your translate provider 
   `$translateProvider.preferredLanguage("en");
   $translateProvider.fallbackLanguage("en");`
7. In `$ionicPlatform.ready` add this code to detect the language when the device is ready:

   ```
   if (typeof navigator.globalization !== "undefined") {
       navigator.globalization.getPreferredLanguage(function (language) {
           var language_list = { "French": "es", "English": "en", "Spanish": "es", "Chinese": "zh", "Japanese": "ja" };
           var language_value = (language.value).split(/[\s,-]+/)[0];

           if (language_list.hasOwnProperty(language_value)) {
               var language_locale = language_list[language_value];
               $translate.use(language_locale).then(function (data) {
                   console.log("SUCCESS -> " + data);
               }, function (error) {
                   console.log("ERROR -> " + error);
               });
           }
       }, null);
   }
   ```

   8. In your view add:

```html
<div class="list">
  <div class="item item-divider">
    {{"language_settings" | translate}}
  </div>
  <label class="item item-radio">
    <input type="radio" name="group" ng-model="language" value="en" ng-change="setLanguage(language)">
    <div class="item-content">
      English
    </div>
    <i class="radio-icon ion-checkmark"></i>
  </label>
  <label class="item item-radio">
    <input type="radio" name="group" ng-model="language" value="ja" ng-change="setLanguage(language)">
    <div class="item-content">
      日本語
    </div>
    <i class="radio-icon ion-checkmark"></i>
  </label>
</div>
```

9. In your language-controller add the following:

```js
app.controller('SettingsController', ['$scope', '$translate', function ($scope, $translate) {
    $scope.getLanguage = function () {
        return $translate.use();
    }
    $scope.language = $scope.getLanguage();
    $scope.setLanguage = function (language_value) {
        $translate.use(language_value).then(function (data) {
            console.log("SUCCESS -> " + data);
        }, function (error) {
            console.log("ERROR -> " + error);
        });


    }
}]);
```

and that's all. If you have any questions, don't hesitate to ask me guys.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my own problem. 
I changed

```
app.controller('TodoCtrl', function ($scope, $timeout, $ionicModal, Projects, $ionicSideMenuDelegate, $location, $anchorScroll, $ionicScrollDelegate, $ionicPopup, $translateProvider) {
```

to

```
app.controller('TodoCtrl', function ($scope, $timeout, $ionicModal, Projects, $ionicSideMenuDelegate, $location, $anchorScroll, $ionicScrollDelegate, $ionicPopup,  $translate) {
```

(Changed $translateProvider to $translate)

Answer (score 0):

That's how i used angular-translate ,first download it via bower

```
bower install angular-translate
```

Then include it in index.html

```
<script src="lib/angular-translate/angular-translate.min.js"></script>
```

Add 'pascalprecht.translate' to your app dependencies list

```
    angular.module('starter', ['ionic','ngCordova','pascalprecht.translate','starter.controllers'])

.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider,$translateProvider) {

  var en_translations = {
    app_title : "EasyLight",
    menu_home: "Home",
    menu_about: "About"
  };
  var fr_translations = {
    app_title : "TorcheSimple",
    menu_home: "Principal",
    menu_about: "A Propos"
  };
  $translateProvider
    .translations('en', en_translations)
    .translations('fr',fr_translations)
    .preferredLanguage('en');
  /*
   ....
  */

});
```

You should use $translateProvider from .config() 
From your template you can use the translations with a translate filter ,for example

```
<h1> {{ "app_title" | trasnlate }}</h1>
```